# Jelastic: automatically update nginx upstream when Automatic Horizontal Scaling is triggered

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy, jelastic, horizontal-scaling

I would like to use Automatic Horizontal Scaling in Jelastic, but this would only make sense if it could automatically update the relevant upstream in nginx.conf when a node is added/removed.

Example: Automatic Horizontal Scaling is triggered for my Node.js server application and a new node is added. It should also automatically update in each Nginx node's nginx.conf all upstreams where the Node.js master node's ip is specified.

How could this be achieved?

I have read all related docs such as [Jelastic Automatic Horizontal Scaling](https://www.virtuozzo.com/application-platform-docs/automatic-horizontal-scaling/) and have not found a solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

That is already the expected behaviour. I recommend to discuss with your hosting provider in case you've found a bug.

You can also potentially write your own logic using the [onAfterScaleOut](https://docs.cloudscripting.com/creating-manifest/events/#onafterscaleout) event.

Comment: I've been using a custom nginx.conf for so long that I forgot that nginx-jelastic.conf and conf.d files even existed. Thank you and sorry!

However, this doesn't solve my problem as it only updates the upstream file of the "Server Applications" spot, which is /etc/nginx/upstreams/common.

In addition to my Node.js app, I have at least 4 other apps in my env that need AHS. Obviously, those can't share the unique "Server Applications" spot obviously and either use the VPS spot or a custom one with a Custom Container Image.

Or this is already supported and I missed something again?

Comment: Did you look at the cloudscripting link? That is how to extend the functionality to handle those custom requirements.

Comment: Yes, quite familiar now. The problem is that we only have the jelastic/nginxbalancer image at disposal, but this doesn't help much as it only has "automatic detection of the application server backends". Forking it just to add AHS support for other applications wouldn't be efficient. Also, it would take a lot of time to write a bottom-up custom JPS implementation without an example and I don't know how my additional JPS events would interfere with the current implementatation contained in the jelastic/nginxbalancer image.

Edit: AHS doesn't even work when using the custom image.

Comment: Can your hosting provider assist you with the JPS?